# Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.HSQDialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am getting the below error when running my application.

My DataConfiguration File

```
package com.book.data;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.book.data")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.book.data")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DataConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource()
    {
        EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
        return builder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory()
    {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter= new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto","create-drop");
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect","org.hibernate.dialect.HSQDialect");

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory=new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.setPackagesToScan("com.book.data");
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factory.getObject();

    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager()
    {
        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
        return txManager;
    }

}
```

Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.HSQDialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.selectStrategyImplementor(StrategySelectorImpl.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveDefaultableStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveDefaultableStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.constructDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:259)
    ... 69 more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this property

```
jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect","org.hibernate.dialect.HSQDialect");
```

This means that project should to have a class `org.hibernate.dialect.HSQDialect` in the class path. You could check that.

There is `HSQLDialect` class in the Hibernate core jar.

Comment: My bad i spelled it wrongly, HSQLDialect not HSQDialect ..Thanks for the direction